# Assert.AreEqual to not fail when comparing an enum and an int

Tags: c#, .net

I'm not sure if this is doable, but I will just give a shot.

I am calling Assert.AreEqual() method.
For the parameters, I'm passing...

1. an enum value which has Int32 as the underlying type because I didn't specify the base type
2. an int (Int32) value

**Assert fails because it sees that the enum is not int** (which is definitely correct).
However, is there a way to make this Assert pass when the enum has the correct int value as the 2nd parameter?

**I can cast the enum to int and have it a quick fix, but it's really ugly.**
I was expecting some kind of overriding a method that Assert uses to compare 2 different objects and implicitly make that enum type look like an int. However, I wasn't successful at finding any hint/answer around that so far.

Someone suggested to [create a type converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayybcxe5.aspx) and use the [TypeConverterAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverterattribute.aspx) to get around. If this works for sure and is the only way to do it, I would; however, it does seem a lot of unnecessary work.

Comment: What's ugly about casting an `enum` to an `int`? How about casting the `int` to the `enum` type instead? Why do you have values of different type to compare with each other in the first place?

Comment: @codingbear: please don't repeat tags in the title line.

Comment: @Fredrik: why is it like this in the first place? no idea. I'm not the one who wrote this. I just want to incorporate enums so that the code is more readable. Without enums, I keep going back to this doc where it contains all the mappings (which enums can easily solve) to verify. Right now, if I decide to change the int to return the same enum type, that's going to cost a lot of time that I don't have, and potentially break other ppl's code.

Comment: So, you've convinced yourself that using enums is a waste of your time?  Then don't do it.

Comment: @Hans: Where/when did I state that using enums is "waste of time"? I would totally do it if I have the time to change the whole framework that is built around this and resolve any issues with people who are consuming this framework.

Comment: Which unit-testing framework? I assume NUnit, but you don't actually say.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By calling `Assert.AreEqual(enum, int)`, you are calling the `Assert.AreEqual(object, object)` method, as there is no overload that has an `enum` and an `int` as parameters.

I do not think that casting the `enum` to an `int` is ugly - in fact I think it is perfectly acceptable and a very common technique. If you were doing a normal equality comparison (ie. 1 == MyEnum.Value), you would get a compiler error as there is no implicit conversion, only an explicit one which requires a cast to work.

A type converter may work, but you need to ask yourself if doing that will actually give you any real benefit for the amount of effort involved. Personally, I would just leave the cast to an `int`.

If you are asserting something like the return value of a method call, why not just assert based on what value you expect?

```
MyEnum actual = SomeMethod();
Assert.AreEqual(MyEnum.Value, actual);
```

This does not require the cast as the two types are the same, and you are asserting the expected value.

Comment: "A type converter may work, but you need to ask yourself if doing that will actually give you any real benefit for the amount of effort involved" - definitely why I'm not even going to try. For now, I'm living it with casting to int. Someday, I hope to rewrite some of that code to return the enum instead of int.

Comment: I agree, conversion of `enum` to `int` will always succeed (even with character enumerations). Not ugly at all.

Answer (score 0):

> I was expecting some kind of overriding a method that Assert uses to compare 2 different objects and implicitly make that enum type look like an int.

That won't work, since `Assert.AreEqual` is a static method, and you cannot override static methods, nor can you add overloads for static methods through extension methods.

Anyway, even if you could, you would violate the contract for `Assert.AreEqual`. You want to have `Assert.AreEqual(myEnum.One, 1)` yield true, although `myEnum.One.Equals(1)` as well as `1.Equals(myEnum.One)` return false. That's inconsistent.

Casting to `int` is not ugly, it's the correct solution to your problem. After all, you want to check if *the numerical value of the enum* matches some integer. If that's what you want to check, write it down like this.

Comment: I wasn't really thinking about overriding Assert.AreEqual, because as you said, it is indeed a static method. However, I was looking for some insights on what Assert.AreEqual method calls under the hood (probably just equals method of the corresponding object). As I stated at the top, I wasn't sure if this is doable. I just wanted to avoid casting, because I always think casting is ugly if I have to do it every time. I guess this situation is not one of those ones that look ugly even if I have to do it every time. :)